# Why does my batch file keep on closing?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I cannot figure out why this keeps on closing after the set /p opo= line.
I enter the operation and then it closes, It doesn't come up with :mult code either.

Here is my code:

```
title Calculator
color 0e
@echo off
GOTO calculator_main
:calculator_main
echo Enter a operation:
set /p opo=
if %opo%=='*'(
GOTO mult
)

if %opo%=='+'(
GOTO add
)

if %opo%=='-'(
GOTO sub
)

if %opo%=='/'(
GOTO div
)


:mult

echo Enter a number:
set /p num1=
echo Enter a number:
set /p num2=
set /a sum=%num1%*%num2%
echo %num1% * %num2% = %sum%
GOTO: calculator_main

pause
```

I would be very grateful if somebody told me why on earth this is happening,

Oscar.

Comment: First rule of debugging a batch file. Run the batch file from the cmd prompt so that you can see any errors it is producing.  Second rule: Don't use @ECHO OFF while debugging a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if %opo%=='*'(
```

should be

```
if %opo%=='*' (
```

The space is required. Your code would attempt to test the string you entered as `opo` against `'*'(` (literally, including the <kbd>'</kbd>s and the <kbd>(</kbd>

If you actually want to test for an entry of `*` then use

```
if "%opo%"=="*" (
```

where the <kbd>"</kbd> delimit the two strings so that they may contain spaces.

If you run the routine directly from the command prompt rather than point, click and giggle, you would see a syntax-error report.

OR

you could investigate the `choice` command (either `choice /?` from the prompt, or use `search` to find examples on SO)